# Bluetooth not recognized for Segar laptop with Intel 8 chipset

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, intel, adapter

I originally got my bluetooth mouse to work after installing blueman.  Then, it stopped.  I do not recall what was updated on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.10.  I can only tell you that it stopped and now bluetooth does not see my adapter, much less any devices.  My problem is similar, if not identical, to:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/572658/bluetooth-service-fails-to-start?newreg=a6c116c0b50e47f5bd40a29c7556f669

Relevant details:

`bud@nikotama:~⟫ uname -a
Linux nikotama 3.16.0-29-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 15 22:27:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

bud@nikotama:~⟫ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Texas Instruments XIO2213A/B/XIO2221 PCI Express to PCI Bridge [Cheetah Express] (rev 01)
04:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments XIO2213A/B/XIO2221 IEEE-1394b OHCI Controller [Cheetah Express] (rev 01)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
05:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
bud@niko

bud@nikotama:~⟫ dmesg | grep luet
[    4.763439] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    4.763450] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.763455] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.763456] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.763462] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.373884] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.373887] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.373893] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.381275] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.381284] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.381288] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    6.851218] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x080f tx timeout

FYI, grepping for firmware or patch produces nothing additional.

`bud@nikotama:~⟫ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no`

The hci0 was soft blocked but I turned off.  Nothing changed.

`bud@nikotama:~⟫ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 80:56:F2:A5:8E:80  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
        DOWN 
        RX bytes:558 acl:0 sco:0 events:28 errors:0
        TX bytes:353 acl:0 sco:0 commands:29 errors:1
        Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x8f
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT`

bud@nikotama:~⟫ sudo hciconfig hci0 down

bud@nikotama:~⟫ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)

I see the type of GUI problems, with the bluetooth manager toggle flipping to on, but nothing happens.  Blueman cannot see the adapter.  I installed all the bluez addons and linux-firmware-nonfree, but none of this produced any change.

`bud@nikotama:~⟫ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    13049  1 
ccm                    17731  1 
vmnet                  51277  13 
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport    26329  0 
vsock                  34903  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vmw_vmci               63011  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vmmon                  84057  0 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23256  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             27605  0 
vboxdrv               418013  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bbswitch               13943  0 
nvram                  14423  0 
rfcomm                 69509  0 
bnep                   19543  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47547  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    76887  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    68914  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
uvcvideo               810firewire_core          68671  1 firewire_ohci
ahci                   34062  6 
psmouse               106548  0 
libahci                32424  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               46301  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
dm_mirror              22040  0 
mii                    13934  1 r8169
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
dm_region_hash         20850  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18411  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror`

If you need anything else, let me know.  FWIW, wireless is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very similar to the issues I had with my Atheros bluetooth.  Here is what I did to fix `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf`
And then I edited /etc/rc.local so it would load ath3k later in the boot process
`gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
And add `modprobe ath3k` above the last line that needs to be `exit 0`
Then save, exit gedit, and reboot
It seems there is a bug in how linux handles xhci and a timing issue prevents ath3k from loading firmware and about 30% of the attempts at boot are successful